# TeXmaker opening multiple instances of the same file

Tags: texmaker

I'm working with a document I have split into several pieces and gathered them in one "master file".

While writing, I switch between the different files using the structure tree or the arrows beside the name of the current file, much like with tabs in a browser.

When one file is already opened and I click again on this file in the structure tree, the file opens again; I then have two instances of the same file open. I run the risk of editing two different files and I can save only one; it happened to me a couple of times.

Is it possible to change something in TeXmaker so that, whenever I click on a file already open, the corresponding tab becomes active instead of opening a new instance of the file?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I don't know which version ? Currently its [4.0.1](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)

Comment: I cannot replicate the behaviour reported by @Simon in TeXmaker 4.01 on Mac OS 10.8.3. When I double click (in the structure tree) on a file already open, no new instance of that file is opened; instead, the tab associated with that file just becomes the active one in the editor.

Comment: It's clear that you have some bug. But usually when you edit an open file using other editor or even the same on other tab, it shows a message warning that file was updated and you have the choice to reload it or not before saving it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. I got TeXmaker 3.5 on Windows 7 (64 bit, servicepack 1). It doesn't always happen, but I never noticed a special point/action when it starts. So I'm usually working, switch tabs and getting confident that its working today and than I sit there with two changed x-hundred lines long files and have to check where I inserted what. So I just have to be a bit more cautious and I will let the people here know, when I've found something out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which doesn't seem to be reproduced in the latest release of the editor involved.